# Do we say "the boy is turning the table around" or "the boy is spinning the table around"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

[image]

The boy is holding the corner of the table as shown in the above picture.

He then goes around and around, which makes the table move around and around (many rounds).

Do we say "**the boy is turning the table around**" or "**the boy is spinning the table around**"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say
**"The boy is turning the table around and around."**
or
**"The boy is turning the table round and round."**

As others have said:

> the boy is turning the table around

You would probably think that he is turning it just one full rotation or less.
"around" is not needed and putting it just once suggests 180 or 360 degrees.

> the boy is spinning the table around

"spinning" suggests many rotations, but also some speed or freedom of motion. Again, "around" is not needed or could suggest one full or half turn.

"Spinning around and around" would be saying the same thing twice.

Answer (score 0):

"Spinning" sounds more natural and is less likely to be ambiguous in this case. A person spinning a table is almost certainly doing it on the vertical axis as in your picture, and could be spinning it around and around multiple times. If you say someone is turning a table around I would normally imagine them only turning it around once, so that it faces the other way. It's also a bit too close to overturning a table, which would be to tip it up on its end.

Comment: I would disagree. _Spinning_ implies a fast motion round a central point, like a spinning top or a roulette wheel. I wouldn't describe a table being dragged round on the floor as spinning.

Comment: I assumed it was a fast motion from the question, which says that he is making "the table move around and around (many rounds)." With a light enough table and low enough friction with the floor it should be possible; but as you say, it is an unusual situation. Normally you wouldn't be able to spin a table.